# How to remove elements from document outline?

Tags: css, accessibility, styled-components, next.js13

I have two sets of layout: mobile and desktop. I use CSS media queries to switch between them, however both of them are visible in document outline. Is there a way to remove elements from document outline if `display: none;` is applied?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible using CSS, you might have to actually remove the unused "branch" using JS DOM methods. _"I have two sets of layout: mobile and desktop."_ - how absolutely _massive_ are the layout differences, that such an approach would be justified?

Comment: It's different layout and different elements used. I can't just shift around stuff using `grid`.

Comment: With `display: none`, the element should no longer be included in the accessibility tree. If you want completely removed from the DOM, the easiest way would be to not render it in the first place. In a CSR React app, `react-responsive` does that just fine. For NextJS/SSR, `@artsy/fresnel` aims to handle breakpoint-dependent rendering gracefully for both client and server rendering: https://github.com/artsy/fresnel.

Comment: Ezra, if I use `display: none;` I still get to see all elements in document outline. I'm using HTML5 Outliner extension for Chrome.